# PasswordBox with DataTrigger and secure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If it right to bind the value of `passwordBox` in `datatrigger`

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=password, Path=Password}" Value="">
     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
 </DataTrigger>
```

`PasswordBox` field

```
 <PasswordBox x:Name="password" PasswordChanged="Password_PasswordChanged" Style="{StaticResource passwordStyle}" />
```

and style resource

```
<Style TargetType="PasswordBox" x:Key="passwordStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="190"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,1,0"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I send the password by interface without binding to ViewModel, for doesn't **keeps the password exposed in memory**

For passwordbox i need block button if the field empty in first app start, because the event PasswordChanged doesn't do that.

but if i bind in trigger it breake this logic or not?

if it right way or may no? if consider the memory.

Comment: You can't bind to the `PasswordBox.Password` property. Nothing will ever happen. Create a `IsPasswordEntered:bool` property in the view that shows the `PasswordBox`. Add a `PasswordBox.PasswordChanged` event handler and use it to set the `IsPasswordEntered` property to `true`. When you bind the `Button.IsEnabled` directly to this property it will toggle between enabled and disabled without the need of a `DataTrigger`. Once you extracted the password, reset the `IsPasswordEntered` property.

Comment: Beside the fact that you can't bind to the `PasswordBox.Password` property, your assumptions are right.  As soon as you access this property, the `PasswordBox` will decrypt the password and therefore create a plain text string instance in the local memory. Unless the getter is invoked, the value of this property is `String.Empty`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your actual issue is? Is the button enabled or disabled as expected?

Comment: @BionicCode - sorry that so long (traveling a bit). Well I need to write this check without bindings and triggers, but how do that, i don't know, because it will save in memory cache (you confirmed my guesses). But `PasswordBox.PasswordChanged` - doesn't work when the page download first time and the `button - IsEnable= true`, but i need to block that in this time(other validation i write without problem but `PasswordChanged`) event.

Comment: @mm8 - how write the block `passwordbox` when the field is empty `PasswordChanged` - doesn't work in the moment when the page start first time ( because event `PasswordChanged` doesn't work in this time)
and do that without binding( for security)